# Spring JPA Hikari multiple connection pool with same datasource

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hikaricp

I'm using Spring JPA for connecting to the data source. My requirement is to have multiple connection pools to the same data source so that I can manage the DB operations based on priority

Is there a way to have multiple connection pools with the same data source?

I was going through this [example](https://www.stubbornjava.com/posts/database-connection-pooling-in-java-with-hikaricp) and I want to do almost the same thing but with the same datasource using Spring JPA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create even the same `DataSource` just with different pool name.

For example method the will create `DataSource` with different pool name:

```
private javax.sql.DataSource dataSource(String poolName) {
    final HikariDataSource dataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    //...setup DataSource properties
    dataSource.setPoolName(poolName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!! Is there any working example for this with Spring boot. Running into several problems after fixing one after the other

Comment: @Thiru it is working, I think you should ask a new question for specific issue(s) when setting your environment