# Multiple connection pools with shared TransactionManager for the same database in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring JPA to connect to a relational database. I want to have multiple connection pools connecting to the same database so scheduled tasks can't clog up the connection pool for user interactions.

This works fine if I define multiple `DataSource`s like it is described in [Spring JPA Hikari multiple connection pool with same datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52831863/spring-jpa-hikari-multiple-connection-pool-with-same-datasource). Currently I define multiple different `EntityManagerFactoryBean`s and `PlatformTransactionManager`s, one for each `DataSource`. But I would like to be able to use the same physical transaction spanning calls to different `JpaRepositories` backed by different `DataSource`s.

```
@Service
public class FooService {
  // ..

  @Transactional
  public saveFoo(Foo foo) {
    fooRepository.save(foo);
    barService.somethingElse(foo);
  }
}

@Service
public class BarService {

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
  public somethingElse(Foo foo) {
    // BarRepository is backed by another DataSource as FooRepository,
    // but both DataSources connect to the same database
    barRepository.saveAndFlush(new FoobarEvent(foo));
  }
}
```

The call to BarRepository fails for me with:

> InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress

It seems like multiple different `DataSource`s are needed because the `DataSource`s define the connection pool. But since the `PlatformTransactionManager` and the `EntityManagerFactoryBean` references the `DataSource` it's not really possible to have transactions span multiple repositories that are backed by different `DataSource`s because Spring doesn't know that both `DataSource`s point to the same database. Is there a way to configure Spring JPA to achieve what I want?

Comment: No, as eventually the transaction is bound to the connection and you still have 2 (or more) separated connections to the database. So unless you want to configure XA transactions this isn't possible.

Comment: You actually need to implement your own [AbstractRoutingDataSource](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source) - scheduled tasks need to set some kind of context property (ThreadLocal value I believe) and implementation of `AbstractRoutingDataSource` read that property. No need to create multiple EMF and TM.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov This solutions seems to work, would you be willing to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

If your service is running through an interface from your controller, then Transactional method should come on the interface layer method.

And use **javax.persistance.Transactional** class for the annotation instead of **org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional**

and specify **@EnableTransactionManagement** in your application class to enable transactions.